# pasar imagenes a otra actividad

Tags: android, android-studio, google-maps, huawei-mobile-services, hms-core

Buenas noches como se puede pasar imagenes de una actividad a otra en android
esta es mi segunda actividad

```
case R.id.id_restaurante:
 Intent opcion=new Intent();
 opcion.putExtra("mostrarpdi","RESTAURANT");
 opcion.putExtra("mostrar","Restaurante");
 opcion.putExtra("imagen",R.drawable.ic_restaurante);
 setResult(1,opcion);
 finish();
 break;
```

este fragmento de codigo  normal me devuelve el mmostrar pdi y el mostrar
la ctividad donde recupero mi informacion es

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
 super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
 
 if (requestCode == REQ_COD) {
 String pdi = data.getStringExtra("mostrarpdi");
 String mostrar=data.getStringExtra("mostrar");
 Bitmap imagen= (Bitmap)data.getParcelableArrayExtra("imagen");
 recibirpdi.setText(pdi);
 mostrarpdi.setText(mostrar);
 imagenpdi.setImageResource(imagen);
 }
```

si se muestra el pdi y el  mostrar , pero como hago para que se pueda mostrar la imagen. agradeceré sus aportes

Comment: Usa setImageResource() pero envía y recibe el valor de la imagen como entero.

Answer (score 2):

En realidad el valor que estas enviando es un entero, te sugiero cambies a enviar el valor de la imagen de esta forma:

```
opcion.putExtra("imagen", R.drawable.ic_restaurante);
```

y al recibir el valor lo realizarías de esta forma recibiendo el valor de tipo `int` y cargarías la imagen en el `ImageView` usando el método `setImageResource()`:

```
int imagen= data.getIntExtra("imagen");
...
...
imagenpdi.setImageResource(imagen);
```